# Image between fragments in a viewpager while swapping

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Is there a way to add an image (ie. a arrow) between two fragments in a viewpager while swapping the fragments? By default the fragments are just stinking together and at least i want some extra space between the fragment cards.

Any ideas?

With best regards,
Juergen

Comment: did you try adding background to viewpager ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Your View pager & Image  in Frame Layout then

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener's onPageScrolled method

try one of this to add margin between fragment

setPageMargin(int marginPixels)
setPageMarginDrawable(Drawable)
setPageMarginDrawable(int)

after that you can show hide your image with your logic.

Comment: Thank you! Works lika a charm! However, now i need to find how to avoid scaling and show it centered :)